# ProgressBar всегда показывает 100%

Tags: android, progress-bar

Не получается установить прогресс в  ProgressBar. Я задал ему progressDrawable для заполнения бара по мере прогресса, но он не зависимо от прогресса который я устанавливаю - заполняется полностью. В чем может быть проблема? Может свойство какое то не указал?

progress_bar.xml

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_height"
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_progressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/check_progres_background"

        />
```

activity.java

```
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setProgress(70);
```

progressBar зеленого цвета под actionBar'ом
[image]

Comment: скриншот в студию. Устанавливаете вы все правильно.

Comment: @metalurgus готово

Comment: Покажите свой layer-list `check_progres_background.xml`

Comment: check_progress_background покажите

Comment: Да, вы правы, в нем нашел ошибку, с цветами накладка вышла...

Answer (score 3):

Проблема была обнаружена в файле drawable. Ниже привожу рабочий код:

progress_bar.xml

```
  <ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_height"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_progressBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/check_progres_background"

    />
```

activity.java

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_progressBar);
progressBar.setMax(100);
progressBar.setProgress(70);
```

check_progres_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorBackgroundGrey" />
    </shape>
</item>


<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    >
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorGreen" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Скажите, а зачем градиент, если цвета в нем одинаковые?

Comment: @pavlofff код был скопипащен, я заменил!